# Generate video compression artifacts

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have one video and I need to get some copies that video with different artifacts:

1 instance with Blocking

1 instance with Ringing

1 instance with Blurring

1 instance with Color Bleeding

1 instance with Staircase noise

Is it possible to generate those artifacts?

All I found only **"-bsf noise=15000"** in ffmpeg, but i'm getting corrupted video with all mentioned artifacts, but i need to get 1 video = only 1 type of artifacts.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input -crf 51 output.mp4` will give you many artifacts.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thank you, but it generates only blocking.

Comment: hello from the future, you probably either solved this or don't care anymore but-- I think you will have a hard time generating different types of artifacts individually from the same source video. I think you will need a different source video for each type.